# $L^p$ convergence from pointwise convergence and the convergence of $L^p$-norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f,\lbrace f_k\rbrace\in L^p$. 
I want to prove that if $f_k\to f$ a.e. and $\|f_k\|_p\to \|f\|_p$ then $\|f-f_k\|_p\to 0$.

I want to use some tricky Holder-inequality to use $\|f_k-f\|_1\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$ but I couldn't use the condition $\|f_k\|_p\to \|f\|_p$.